# How to best encrypt data-at-rest for users logging in with SAML?

Tags: security, web-applications, public-key-encryption, saml-2.0

I have a web application which allows SAML authentication by users using their own identity provider. I have fields in a database in my application which I want to ensure that only authorized users can decrypt (and developers/administrators of the system are NOT implicitly authorized).  For users logging in with a password this is easy - make an RSA keypair where the private key is encrypted with their login password, and update a keychain if the password ever changes.  But how can this be done when there is no login password, because the user has been authenticated with SAML?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to tell you this, but I don't consider your secure option (derived key) all that secure either.

The reality is that an admin can do very bad things here...including:

- Inject code on the f/e and steal passwords in flight
- Steal the data and do a dictionary attack against the db directly, guessing many possible keys to unlock the data (knowing that the password set is relatively small)

IMO just deriving a key from the password isn't enough. You need to raise the bar materially higher if you want to consider it "best practice." Ideally you could solve both problems with one solution but if you use password as a source (or derived password hashes) then it might not be possible.